# Is there any website or method to calculate the refractive index of gases like $\rm CO_2$ in the mid IR?

Tags: optics, refraction, gas, infrared-radiation, data

I want to know the complex refractive index of some gases like CO2, CH4, C2H6 .. etc in the mid infrared.
Is there any website, software or a method to know them?

Answer (score 0):

Gases are not usually described in terms of refractive index, but in terms of [molecular polarizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility). There is a trivial way to convert this into a refractive index since $n^2 = \epsilon = 1+\chi$. A search on polarizability of Co2 should give you the result.